# SQL Query for update in single table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one table and and it consist of many columns and two of the are group_id and access_id.Now the
problem is caused because of inconsistency of records is as follows-
records are in format of

```
group_id access_id

100      1,
200      1,
300      1,
400      1,
100      2,
200      2,
300      2,
400      2,
100      3,
400      3,
100      4,
300      4,
```

so you can see there is no entry in table for the records of `(group_id,access_id)-> (200,3),(300,3),(200,4),(400,4) ..`
There are unknown number of groups as data is on production server and 1 to 12 `access_id` for each `group_id` .
so I need to form a query that **inserts all records for absent pair of (group_id,access_id).**
--(Sorry for poor editing skills)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: have u tried anything????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EXAMPLE
    (   
        @accessid_range INT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTable(group_id_temp INT, frequency INT)
        INSERT INTO #LocalTempTable(group_id_temp, frequency)
        (SELECT group_id,COUNT(group_id) AS frequency FROM SAMPLE2 GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(group_id)<4);
        --SELECT * FROM #LocalTempTable;

        --SELECT group_id, access_id from SAMPLE2 WHERE group_id IN 
        --(SELECT group_id_temp FROM #LocalTempTable) GROUP BY group_id, access_id;

        DECLARE @GROUPID INT
        DECLARE GROUPIDs CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT group_id_temp FROM #LocalTempTable;

        OPEN GROUPIDs
            FETCH NEXT FROM GROUPIDs into @GROUPID
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                        --PRINT(@GROUPID)
    --***********************************************************************************************************************
                        DECLARE @ACCESSID INT,
                                @COUNTER INT=1;
                        DECLARE ACSESSIDs CURSOR LOCAL FOR SELECT access_id FROM SAMPLE2 WHERE group_id=@GROUPID ORDER BY access_id;

                        OPEN ACSESSIDs
                            FETCH NEXT FROM ACSESSIDs into @ACCESSID
                                WHILE (@COUNTER <=@accessid_range)
                                    BEGIN
                                        --PRINT(@ACCESSID);

                                            IF(@ACCESSID != @COUNTER)
                                                INSERT INTO SAMPLE2 VALUES(@GROUPID,@COUNTER)

                                        SET @COUNTER = @COUNTER + 1
                                        FETCH NEXT FROM ACSESSIDs INTO @ACCESSID
                                    END
                        CLOSE ACSESSIDs
                        DEALLOCATE ACSESSIDs
    --*************************************************************************************************************************
                        FETCH NEXT FROM GROUPIDs into @GROUPID
                    END
        CLOSE GROUPIDs
    END
```

Comment: Cursors takes too much load

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO yourTable
SELECT group_id, t.x AS access_id
FROM yourTable CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT p.x  FROM
(
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)
) P(x)
) AS t
EXCEPT
SELECT group_id, access_id FROM yourTable
```

try this code Replace yourTable on real table name. And first commit INSERT statement for see result SELECT statement